# queryEach or .each() not Working at CF 11, Why?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfquery

I was seaching in google better form to interate over "query" in coldfusion, since im new in the company im working, and im trying to get more from CF

**Here my attempts:**

**My models:**

```
<cffunction hint="Foo" name="Foo" access="public" returntype="query">
    <!--- Argumentos --->
    <cfargument hint="Something" name="ArgComBus" type="string" required="no" default="">
    <cfargument hint="Other thing" name="ArgPar" type="string" required="no" default="">

    <cfscript>
        queryService = new Query();
        queryService.setSql("
            SELECT
                column1,
                column2,
            FROM
                tab_bar
            WHERE
                1=1
                #arguments.ArgComBus#
        ");
        queryService.setDataSource(session.Dsn);

        if(Len(Trim(arguments.ArgPar))){
            Evaluate(arguments.ArgPar);
        }
        queryResult = queryService.execute();
        qBus = queryResult.getResult();
    </cfscript>


    <cfreturn qBus>
</cffunction>
```

**My script**

```
<cfscript>
arrFoo = arrayNew(1);

qFoo = this.Foo(
    ArgComBus = " AND column1 = #variables.bar# ");

// First Attempt - The each method was not found.
qFoo.each(function (foo) {
    arrFoo.append(foo);
});

// Second Attempt - Variable QUERYEACH is undefined.
queryEach(qFoo, function (foo) {
    arrFoo.append(foo);
});

writeDump(arrFoo);
</cfscript>
```

**My Server Dump**

```
InstallKit  Native Windows
appserver   Tomcat
productlevel    Developer
productname ColdFusion Server
productversion  11,0,05,293506
rootdir C:\CFusion11\cfusion
```

I even used `getMetaData()` on my query variable `qFoo` and that return that is array... so when i tried use something like that (trying to convert array in query?)

```
cfQuery = createObject("java", "coldfusion.sql.QueryTable").init(qFoo);
```

`.each()` and `queryEach()` same answer... i even tried use `arrayEach()` but return the object is `coldfusion.sql.QueryTable` and not array

Comment: I wouldn't try tinkering with the coldfusion.sql.QueryTable. I might consider the EntityLoad() aka ORM approach. Especially since you seem to want arrays.

Comment: And I would seriously consider whether looping over a function to call a query is what you want. That will seriously beat on the database and network, when you could make a single database call and then loop over the results to build whatever object you need. Also, watch out for SQL Injection. And `evaluate()`.

Comment: An alternative (if you want to use some more modern syntax in your queries and deal with arrays) is to use QB: https://qb.ortusbooks.com/ -- it will use queryExecute under the hood (which is preferable to new Query()) and return collections or arrays. You can use arrayEach or the .each() member function (which is indeed supported in ACF11).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running ColdFusion 11.

The `queryEach()` function was not added until ColdFusion 2016:

- [reference 1 (from cfdocs)](https://cfdocs.org/cf2016)
- [reference 2 (from Adobe docs)](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/queryeach.html)

**Originally I had posted that the `each()` member function was not available in Adobe ColdFusion 11. Aquitaine pointed out in the comments that it actually is.** I incorrectly referenced the `Each()` function for Lucee that works with collections. The `Each()` function related to this question is actually the script version of the `ArrayEach()` tag function. Which is available in ColdFusion 11 (it was actually added in ColdFusion 10). Sorry for the confusion.

*The documentation may be wrong. I could not get the function to work as `Each()` except under ColdFusion 2018. For ColdFusion 11 I could only get it to work as `ArrayEach()`.*

- [reference 3 (from cfdocs)](https://cfdocs.org/arrayeach)
- [reference 4 (from Adobe docs)](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayeach.html)

Here are a couple of examples on how to loop over a query in ColdFusion 11 (borrowed from cfdocs):

```
// Define our query 
platform = ["Adobe ColdFusion", "Railo", "Lucee"]; 
myQuery = queryNew(" "); 
queryAddColumn(myQuery, "platform", "CF_SQL_VARCHAR", platform); 


// By row index 
for (i = 1; i <= myQuery.recordCount; i++) { 
   writeOutput("<li>#myQuery["platform"][i]#</li>"); 
} 


// By query 
for (row in myQuery) { 
   writeOutput("<li>#row.platform#</li>"); 
}


// By arrayeach 
writeOutput("<h3>By arrayeach:</h3>");
function printArray(vendor, index)
{
    writeOutput("<li>#vendor#</li>");
}
arrayEach(platform,printArray);
```

I created a gist for you on TryCF.com so you can see this code in action and play around with it if you like. [Just click here to run the code](https://trycf.com/gist/f24e7fd022c323846ba045af244472d7/acf11?theme=monokai).

Comment: Good answer, when i was seaching CF11 this queryEach appeared, so i tried to use... i was already using for to interate over it, i was just trying to get something better

Comment: Note that the .each() member function is in ACF11: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/using-the-member-functions.html

Comment: @Aquitaine you are correct. Thank you. I will update my answer.